# Can Interlocked.CompareExchange throw NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, .net

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb297966(v=vs.110).aspx

```
[ComVisibleAttribute(false)]
public static T CompareExchange<T>(
    ref T location1,
    T value,
    T comparand
)
where T : class
```

and

```
NullReferenceException    The address of location1 is a null pointer.
```

But when I use a null reference for `location1`, I don't get any errors:

```
class A { }
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A dest = null;
        A src = new A();
        // If dest is null, then replace with src.
        Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref dest, src, null);
    }
}
```

Is it ok to do this? Is there a danger that this will throw `NullReferenceException` in later versions of .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer says, it's perfectly OK to have your variable contain `null` -- it's about the *reference to the variable* being `null`, and that can't happen in C#, or most other managed languages for that matter.

That said, you *can* make `Interlocked.CompareExchange` throw a `NullReferenceException` by working directly from IL. But even there you have to get tricky if you want to remain in the realm of managed, verifiable code:

```
  .method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
  {
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack  3
    .locals init ([0] int32& x)  // x is initialized to null
    ldloc.0
    ldc.i4.1
    ldc.i4.2
    call  int32 [mscorlib]System.Threading.Interlocked::CompareExchange(
      int32&, int32, int32)
    pop
    ret
  }
```

This code will pass verification, but it will throw a `NullReferenceException` at runtime. The stack trace will not actually show `Interlocked.CompareExchange`, since the JIT compiler inlines it to a single `lock cmpxchg` instruction.

As @Sean correctly pointed out, this should not really justify the documentation saying that the method may throw a `NullReferenceException`, because this technique can be used to break any function taking a `ref` or `out` parameter. For example, [`Int32.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f02979c7) does not document that it can throw a NRE if "the address of `result` is `null`", nor would we expect it to. Managed code is implicitly expected to be well-behaved when it comes to references.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is misleading here, as `location1` cannot be `null` since in C# it must always reference an existing variable.  So yes, it is ok as what you are saying is "set `location1` (that currently contains null) to be `src` if `location1` is already `null`".

In fact because `location1` has to be a reference it is impossible to pass a null-reference in C#, although it it possible (and valid) to pass a reference to something that is null, and so this function will never throw a `NullReferenceException`.

I suspect this is down to the documentation being ported over from the Win32 api, where you have to pass a pointer to the location to read/write the variable, and it would be an error to pass `null` here.

Comment: Well documentation does not say anything about value of location, only about _address_ of location variable. I mean it can be _confusing_ but seems not _misleading_.

Comment: So, impossible to throw in c#. But documentation covers other languages, so in c++ for example is it possible to make it throw do you know?

Comment: @weston - The C++/CLI documentation shows the method taking a managed reference (a `T%`) which I believe the compiler will ensure references an existing variable.

Comment: I believe the underlying .NET IL code can manage to call this method with a null reference. For C#, not so much.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - maybe, but in that case every function that takes a `ref` or `out` parameter would be capable of throwing a `NullReferenceException`.