# Is there some good reason for the return value of Interlocked.CompareExchange

Tags: multithreading, interlocked

The `Interlocked.CompareExchange()` method ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange?view=netframework-4.8)) does roughly speaking this:

"I have a variable, and I think I know what value it currently has. If I'm right, then please change the value to that".

The point being that this method can be used to safely update a variable in a multi-threaded context. If the value has changed since the caller thought it knew what the value was, then some other thread has made that change, so this thread needs to retry (or whatever other behaviour is appropriate)

The return value of `Interlocked.CompareExchange()` is "the original value of the variable".
i.e. the *actual* value of the variable we thought we knew the value of, at the point of invocation.

That seems ... weird.

It seems clear to me that almost every invocation of this method is then going to be followed by comparing the return value with the previously believed value.
i.e. you want to know whether you won the race to update the value.
So the "conversation" goes.

- "I have a variable, which I think has value *X*. If I'm right, please set it to *Y*."
- Then `CompareExchange()` says "The variable had value *Z* when you asked me", which I then compare to my earlier *X* to I infer whether or not I won.

Why doesn't `CompareExchange()` just return a `boolean` success flag? (Much like `TryParse()` et. al.)

The value of the variable at the point of invocation isn't going to be useful barring some very obscure cirumstances, because the value you have immediate goes out of date; other threads could have updated the variable after the return value was received.

**Why return that value, rather than the more obviously useful boolean?**

Comment: The original value is useful when you're spinning inside a loop to wait when the thread wins the race, to use this value as value to compare on the next iteration instead of spending extra CPU cycles on getting the value from memory.

Answer (score 0):

> Why return that value, rather than the more obviously useful boolean?

The value at compare time is more useful than a Boolean. As obscure as you may believe the race conditions may be they are the very reason we have this method. A Boolean return would only indicate that the value was the same as the comparand at the time it was compared.

You can still derive a Boolean by comparing the return to the comparand value. `CompareExchange (location1, value, comparand) == comparand`. In fact this form makes it ideal for a template or macro if you want one.

However, if the return is `false` we only know that the value is different. Reading the value back will not let us know what the actual value at compare time was.

If we had the compared value we could:

- Use that information to find who beat us in the race
- Immediately return that value in case of a singleton (disposing any replacements as needed).